# How to change the text of UIBarButtonItem programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've read this article:
[Change the text of a UILabel (UIBarButtonItem) on a toolbar programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225457/change-the-text-of-a-uilabel-uibarbuttonitem-on-a-toolbar-programmatically)

But it seems not working for my auto-hide toolbar?
I also tried `barbuttonItem.title` to set the text, failed too.

Any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you creating the button in `Interface Builder`?  Make sure that the identifier is set to Custom, otherwise you will not be able to change the title.

Select the `UIBarButtonItem` in `Interface Builder`, open the inspector `(Command + Shift + I)`, and select "Custom" under the dropdown next to `Identifier`.

Comment: Does your "set to Custom" mean "initWithCustomView"?
If so, my item was already set to Custom.
  like this:
 percentage = [[UILabel alloc] init];
 percentage.text = @"HELLO";
 UIBarButtonItem *percentageBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:percentage]; 

  I want to keep it changeable after putting it on the toolbar.

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to make up in comment.../_\

Comment: If you are simply using text, I would recommend calling

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style target:(id)target action:(SEL)action

Then you can change the title later with ease.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. Could I ask one more question? Howto change the value of UIBarButtonItem slider in the same condition(i.e., auto-hide toolbar)

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *clearButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Clear" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(yourMethod:)];
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Create an `IBOutlet` for the `UIBarButtonItem` , outToMyButton in this example
2. synthesize in `.m`
3. `outToMyButton.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",myInt]; // or any NSString init`

Answer (score 4):

Changing the title of a `UIBarButtonItem` programmatically:

```
@interface YourController : UIViewController
{
  UIBarButtonItem *barButton;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Set", @"Set")
                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                              target:self
                                              action:@selector(barButtonClicked)];
}
```

And the `BarButtonItem` action:

```
- (void)barButtonClicked
{
  if([barButton.title isEqualToString:@"Set"])
  {
    //Enter Code
    barButton.title = @"Done"
  }
  else
  {
    //Enter Code
    barButton.title = @"Set"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The question was changing the text of UIBarButtonItem programmatically :

So here is how you do it.
an example would be putting the weather info into the bar.

```
import UIKit
...

@IBOutlet weak var weatherBarLabel: UIBarButtonItem!


//then
func setTheWeatherInfo(weather: WeatherModel){
 weatherBarLabel.title = "\(weather.temperature)°"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that my problem was similar -- but not identical -- to yours: I wanted the text on an accessory toolbar to reflect selections of the last picker component.

I was, however, unable to change the text of a `UILabel` added to a `UIBarButtonItem` that is part of an `inputAccessoryView` displayed over a multiple-component sliding `UIPickerView` for each of several data-entry `UITextFields`. These elements are created programmatically **(Xcode v 4.3 (4E109)**), except for the text fields, each of which is created in the **Storyboard** and declared as a property.

Neither assigning the text to the toolbarTitle label, and then alloc/init-ing the bar button item with toolbarTitle as a custom view:

```
toolbarTitle.text = @"myTextFromPickerComponent";
UIBarButtonItem *title = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbarTitle];

//nor alloc/init-ing the bar button item directly, passing the new text to initWithTitle:

UIBarButtonItem *title = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:toolbarTitle.text style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:nil];
```

Gave the desired behavior; i.e., the label text did not change, even though I confirmed with NSLog that I indeed was sending the new text.

I got a hint from the Docs under `Custom Views for Data Input`, `Input Views and InputAccessory Views`:

"The first responder can reload the input and accessory views by calling the `reloadInputViews` method of `UIResponder`."

I implemented this by having the current `UITextField` call `reloadInputViews`, and this worked for me with either of the two code fragments given above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: calling reloadInputViews.