# xCode - tool bar button item label change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, toolbar

In my project ("Xcode 4.3.2 - Single View Application"), I have manually added a ToolBar with a button item, i need to update the button label programatically.
How can i do this? Could you please help me?

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webDisplay;
    IBOutlet UIToolbar *menuBar; //my toolBar
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIWebView *webDisplay;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIToolbar *menuBar;

- (IBAction) changeLabel:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction) changeLabel:(id)sender{

  //code for updating label

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the text of a UILabel (UIBarButtonItem) on a toolbar programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225457/change-the-text-of-a-uilabel-uibarbuttonitem-on-a-toolbar-programmatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webDisplay;
    IBOutlet UIToolbar *menuBar; //my toolBar
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *barButton;
}
...

- (IBAction) changeLabel:(id)sender{

barButton.title = @"test";

}
```

Be sure to set the BarButtonItem as Referencing Outlet "barButton"

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{

IBOutlet UIWebView *webDisplay;
IBOutlet UIToolbar *menuBar; //my toolBar

  UIButton* btnBack;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIWebView *webDisplay;

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIToolbar *menuBar;

- (IBAction) changeLabel:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnBack setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 49, 30)];
[btnBack setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnBack.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
UIBarButtonItem *abackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack]



- (IBAction) changeLabel:(id)sender{

//code for updating label
[btnBack setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Detail_Back", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```