# How to change Title of UIBarButtonItem when button is clicked - iPhone

Tags: ios, ios5, uibarbuttonitem, navigationitem

I'm trying to change the title of UIBarButtonItem when button is clicked.  Here's the code that I have... but it doesn't work.

```
UIBarButtonItem * btnleft1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test2" 
                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                                      target:self
                                                      action:@selector(TestingThis:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btn, btnleft, btnleft1, nil];

- (void)TestingThis:(id)sender {
    if (self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title == @"Test2") {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"Done";
    }
    else
    {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"Test2";
    }
}
```

So that's the code that I'm using.  Please keep in mind that button "btnleft1" is in rightBarButtonItem"S" and not in rightBarButtonItem.  If i change it to rightbarbuttonitems.title... it gives me an error.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but for future reference, you can use custom button to do this :

```
      CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 6, 60, 30);
      UIButton *customButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
      [customButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [customButton setTitle:@"Undone" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
      [customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectDoneClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton ];
      [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the title explicitly.
You can do this with code:`[(UIBarButtonItem *)item setTitle:@"someText"];`

Here's a helpful link: [Change the text of a UILabel (UIBarButtonItem) on a toolbar programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225457/change-the-text-of-a-uilabel-uibarbuttonitem-on-a-toolbar-programmatically)
Hope this helped!

Comment: Even if I put this on my (void) TestingThis [(UIBarButtonItem *)btnleft1 setTitle:@"Test5"];    

It wont rename it.  Basically I want to be able to press btnleft1 and change its title from Test2 to Done and vice versa